# Stop a function after certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, gsap

I have a little preloader made with greensock to follow my mouse but when it gets bigger after the animation I want it to stop following the mouse but I can't find a code that will do that neither with greensock nor jQuery/javascript.

`codepen link`http://codepen.io/amirhanif/pen/GjbjNe

```js
var self = this;
self.hello = 'hello';
var $fade = $('.fade-bounce');
var $circle = $('.icon');
var movementTimer = null;

TweenMax.to($circle, 3, {
  repeat: 2,
  rotation: 760,
  transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
  ease: Bounce.easeOut,
  margin: " 0 auto"
});
TweenMax.to(
  $circle, 500, {
    repeat: -1,
    rotation: 50,
    delay: 7
  });
TweenMax.to(
  $circle,
  1, {
    width: "800vh",
    overflow: "hidden",
    delay: 7,
    y: "-50%",
    transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
    x: "-50%",
    ease: Quad.easeInOut
  });
TweenMax.staggerFrom($fade,
  1, {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 0.1,
    delay: 8,
    ease: Bounce.easeOut
  }, 1.1);



$(window).on('mousemove', moveCircle);


function moveCircle(e) {
  TweenLite.to($circle, 0.2, {
    css: {
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    }

  });

}
```

```css
$color1:#3f88c5;
 body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
.bg-home {
  background-color: $color1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.icon-holder {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
}
.icon {
  margin: 20px auto;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.st0 {
  fill: #F6A900;
}
.st1 {
  fill: #F9CC00;
}
.bigM {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-top: 20%;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
.contentInlog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
}
.win {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(' ../img/hoofdtekst.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(' ../img/logo.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.fade-bounce {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
  <div class="bg-home"></div>
  <div class="icon-holder small-12 columns">
    <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
      <circle class="st0" cx="199.5" cy="199.7" r="191.1" />
      <path class="st1" d="M199.8 390.8l1-191.1c2.3 0-2.3 0.3 0 0l26.1 189.2C218 390.1 208.8 390.8 199.8 390.8zM172.7 388.9c-9-1.3-18-3.2-26.7-5.8l54.8-183.5c2.2 0.6-2.3-0.3 0 0L172.7 388.9zM253.6 383.1l-52.8-183.4c2.2-0.6-2.1 0.9 0 0l78.4 173.8C270.9 377.3 262.3 380.5 253.6 383.1zM120.4 373.6c-8.3-3.8-16.3-8.2-24-13.1l104.3-160.8c1.9 1.2-2.1-1 0 0L120.4 373.6zM303.1 360.4L200.8 199.7c1.9-1.2-1.8 1.5 0 0l124.1 144.4C318 350 310.7 355.5 303.1 360.4zM74.6 344.2c-6.8-5.9-13.3-12.4-19.2-19.2l145.4-125.3c1.5 1.8-1.8-1.5 0 0L74.6 344.2zM344.1 324.8L200.8 199.7c1.5-1.8-1.2 1.9 0 0L360.5 303C355.6 310.6 350.1 318 344.1 324.8zM39 303.2c-4.9-7.6-9.3-15.7-13.1-23.9l174.8-79.6c0.9 2.1-1.2-1.9 0 0L39 303.2zM373.6 279.1l-172.8-79.4c0.9-2.1-0.6 2.2 0 0l182.4 53.8C380.6 262.2 377.3 270.8 373.6 279.1zM16.3 253.7c-2.6-8.7-4.5-17.7-5.8-26.7l190.2-27.3c0.3 2.3-0.6-2.2 0 0L16.3 253.7zM388.9 226.8l-188.1-27.1c0.3-2.3 0 2.4 0 0l0 0 190-0.3v0.3C390.8 208.7 390.2 217.8 388.9 226.8zM8.6 199.8v-0.1c0-9 0.6-18 1.9-26.9l190.3 26.9c-0.3 2.3 0-2.3 0 0L8.6 199.8zM200.8 199.7C200.4 197.4 201.4 201.8 200.8 199.7L383 145.5c2.6 8.7 4.5 17.7 5.8 26.7L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L16.2 146.1c2.5-8.7 5.8-17.4 9.5-25.6L200.8 199.7C199.8 201.7 201.4 197.5 200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7C199.8 197.6 202 201.6 200.8 199.7L360.2 96c4.9 7.6 9.3 15.7 13.1 23.9L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L38.8 96.5c4.9-7.6 10.4-15 16.3-21.8L200.8 199.7C199.2 201.4 202 197.7 200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7C199.2 197.9 202.5 201.2 200.8 199.7L324.6 55c6.8 5.9 13.3 12.4 19.3 19.2L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L74.3 55.4c6.8-5.9 14.2-11.4 21.8-16.4L200.8 199.7C198.8 200.9 202.5 198.1 200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7C198.8 198.4 202.8 200.6 200.8 199.7l78.1-174c8.3 3.8 16.3 8.2 24 13.1L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L120 25.9c8.3-3.8 16.9-7 25.6-9.6L200.8 199.7C198.6 200.3 202.8 198.7 200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7C198.6 199 203 200 200.8 199.7l25.7-189.2c9 1.3 18 3.2 26.7 5.7L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L172.3 10.5c8.9-1.3 18-1.9 27.1-2L200.8 199.7C198.4 199.7 203 199.3 200.8 199.7z"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="bigM small-12 large-10 columns ">
    <img ng-src="img/BigM.png" width="80%" height="auto">
  </div>

  <div class="contentInlog">

    <div class="win small-12 large-10 columns fade-bounce">

    </div>
    <div class="logo small-12 large-10 fade-bounce"></div>

    <form>
      <!-- <section class="content">
        <span class="input input--jiro">
     <input class="input__field input__field--jiro" type="text" id="input-10" />
     <label class="input__label input__label--jiro" for="input-10">
      <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--jiro">Voer u email in</span>
        </label>
        </span>
        <span class="input input--jiro">
     <input class="input__field input__field--jiro" type="text" id="input-11" />
     <label class="input__label input__label--jiro" for="input-11">
      <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--jiro" value="dd/mm/yy">Wat is u geboortedatum?</span>
        </label>
        </span>
    <span class="input input--jiro">
     <input class="input_submit"  type="submit" value="DOE MEE" id="input-12" />
        </span>
    </section> -->

    </form>


  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Please post your code within the question. If CodePen goes down this question will be unanswerable

Comment: Use a callback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815648/tweenmax-callback-being-executed-before-the-animation-end

Comment: thanks Rory i wil upload it in the question,  But it does not work storing a callback function in the mousemouve function is displays an error of u are using :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation end with in `7sec` so i was applied with `setTimeout()` for `7sec`. After `7sec` the mouse over event will be disabled.

```js
var self = this;
self.hello = 'hello';
var $fade = $('.fade-bounce');
var $circle = $('.icon');
var movementTimer = null;

TweenMax.to($circle, 3, {
  repeat: 2,
  rotation: 760,
  transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
  ease: Bounce.easeOut,
  margin: " 0 auto"
});
TweenMax.to(
  $circle, 500, {
    repeat: -1,
    rotation: 50,
    delay: 7
  });
TweenMax.to(
  $circle,
  1, {
    width: "800vh",
    overflow: "hidden",
    delay: 7,
    y: "-50%",
    transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
    x: "-50%",
    ease: Quad.easeInOut
  });
TweenMax.staggerFrom($fade,
  1, {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 0.1,
    delay: 8,
    ease: Bounce.easeOut
  }, 1.1);



$(window).on('mousemove', moveCircle);
setTimeout(function () {$(window).off('mousemove', moveCircle);},7000);

function moveCircle(e) {
  TweenLite.to($circle, 0.2, {
    css: {
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    }

  });

}
```

```css
$color1:#3f88c5;
 body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
.bg-home {
  background-color: $color1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.icon-holder {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
}
.icon {
  margin: 20px auto;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.st0 {
  fill: #F6A900;
}
.st1 {
  fill: #F9CC00;
}
.bigM {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-top: 20%;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
.contentInlog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
}
.win {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(' ../img/hoofdtekst.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(' ../img/logo.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.fade-bounce {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
  <div class="bg-home"></div>
  <div class="icon-holder small-12 columns">
    <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
      <circle class="st0" cx="199.5" cy="199.7" r="191.1" />
      <path class="st1" d="M199.8 390.8l1-191.1c2.3 0-2.3 0.3 0 0l26.1 189.2C218 390.1 208.8 390.8 199.8 390.8zM172.7 388.9c-9-1.3-18-3.2-26.7-5.8l54.8-183.5c2.2 0.6-2.3-0.3 0 0L172.7 388.9zM253.6 383.1l-52.8-183.4c2.2-0.6-2.1 0.9 0 0l78.4 173.8C270.9 377.3 262.3 380.5 253.6 383.1zM120.4 373.6c-8.3-3.8-16.3-8.2-24-13.1l104.3-160.8c1.9 1.2-2.1-1 0 0L120.4 373.6zM303.1 360.4L200.8 199.7c1.9-1.2-1.8 1.5 0 0l124.1 144.4C318 350 310.7 355.5 303.1 360.4zM74.6 344.2c-6.8-5.9-13.3-12.4-19.2-19.2l145.4-125.3c1.5 1.8-1.8-1.5 0 0L74.6 344.2zM344.1 324.8L200.8 199.7c1.5-1.8-1.2 1.9 0 0L360.5 303C355.6 310.6 350.1 318 344.1 324.8zM39 303.2c-4.9-7.6-9.3-15.7-13.1-23.9l174.8-79.6c0.9 2.1-1.2-1.9 0 0L39 303.2zM373.6 279.1l-172.8-79.4c0.9-2.1-0.6 2.2 0 0l182.4 53.8C380.6 262.2 377.3 270.8 373.6 279.1zM16.3 253.7c-2.6-8.7-4.5-17.7-5.8-26.7l190.2-27.3c0.3 2.3-0.6-2.2 0 0L16.3 253.7zM388.9 226.8l-188.1-27.1c0.3-2.3 0 2.4 0 0l0 0 190-0.3v0.3C390.8 208.7 390.2 217.8 388.9 226.8zM8.6 199.8v-0.1c0-9 0.6-18 1.9-26.9l190.3 26.9c-0.3 2.3 0-2.3 0 0L8.6 199.8zM200.8 199.7C200.4 197.4 201.4 201.8 200.8 199.7L383 145.5c2.6 8.7 4.5 17.7 5.8 26.7L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L16.2 146.1c2.5-8.7 5.8-17.4 9.5-25.6L200.8 199.7C199.8 201.7 201.4 197.5 200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7C199.8 197.6 202 201.6 200.8 199.7L360.2 96c4.9 7.6 9.3 15.7 13.1 23.9L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L38.8 96.5c4.9-7.6 10.4-15 16.3-21.8L200.8 199.7C199.2 201.4 202 197.7 200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7C199.2 197.9 202.5 201.2 200.8 199.7L324.6 55c6.8 5.9 13.3 12.4 19.3 19.2L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L74.3 55.4c6.8-5.9 14.2-11.4 21.8-16.4L200.8 199.7C198.8 200.9 202.5 198.1 200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7C198.8 198.4 202.8 200.6 200.8 199.7l78.1-174c8.3 3.8 16.3 8.2 24 13.1L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L120 25.9c8.3-3.8 16.9-7 25.6-9.6L200.8 199.7C198.6 200.3 202.8 198.7 200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7C198.6 199 203 200 200.8 199.7l25.7-189.2c9 1.3 18 3.2 26.7 5.7L200.8 199.7zM200.8 199.7L172.3 10.5c8.9-1.3 18-1.9 27.1-2L200.8 199.7C198.4 199.7 203 199.3 200.8 199.7z"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="bigM small-12 large-10 columns ">
    <img ng-src="img/BigM.png" width="80%" height="auto">
  </div>

  <div class="contentInlog">

    <div class="win small-12 large-10 columns fade-bounce">

    </div>
    <div class="logo small-12 large-10 fade-bounce"></div>

    <form>
      <!-- <section class="content">
        <span class="input input--jiro">
     <input class="input__field input__field--jiro" type="text" id="input-10" />
     <label class="input__label input__label--jiro" for="input-10">
      <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--jiro">Voer u email in</span>
        </label>
        </span>
        <span class="input input--jiro">
     <input class="input__field input__field--jiro" type="text" id="input-11" />
     <label class="input__label input__label--jiro" for="input-11">
      <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--jiro" value="dd/mm/yy">Wat is u geboortedatum?</span>
        </label>
        </span>
    <span class="input input--jiro">
     <input class="input_submit"  type="submit" value="DOE MEE" id="input-12" />
        </span>
    </section> -->

    </form>


  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: @amirhanif Don't forget.If the answer is helpfull give a upvote. or if Answer is satisfied your question.please [tick mark as a answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).Its helpfull for future visitors.

Comment: thanks i think i voted it as an answer but the vote thing does not work it displays Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.